# How do I do the following code (making urls clickable and images show) with jQuery instead of dojo?

Tags: jquery

I'm rewriting an userscript and replacing the use of dojo with jQuery, but then I came upon something, I got lost. :(

This is the script with dojo, it worked fine:

```
dojo.query(".body").forEach(function(node, index, arr){
      kmfa.check(node,index);
});

kmfa.check = function(node){    //check for links/images and replace some stuff
   regex= /(https?:\/\/([-\wäöü\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([-=_\w\.\%\@\#\~;:,\(\)\/\+]*(\?[^<>\s]+)?)?)?)/gi;
   node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace( /<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/gi, '$1' );
   node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace( /<wbr>/g, '' );
   if (node.innerHTML.indexOf('.png') != -1 || node.innerHTML.indexOf('.gif') != -1 ||  node.innerHTML.indexOf('.jpg') != -1 || node.innerHTML.indexOf('.tif') != -1 || node.innerHTML.indexOf('.bmp') != -1){
       node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace( regex, '<img src="$1" class="imgLimit" ></br><a href="$1">$1</a>' );    
   }else{
       node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace( regex, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>' ); 
   }
}
```

Now how do I get this to work with jQuery?

All I got so far is:

```
$('#forum').each(function (ind){
    $(this).text(kmsi.replaceURLWithHTMLLinks($(this).text() ) )    
});

kmsi.replaceURLWithHTMLLinks = function(text) {
   var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
   return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

but that isn't working at all.

(I figure there will be comments like 'why change to jQuery when you have it working?'. to answer those beforehand: i just wanna learn jQuery!)

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Could you post some example html on which you know the dojo version has the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things I can see that are wrong:

First:

```
$('#forum').each(function (ind){
    ....
});
```

`#forum` will select for an element with id forum. as an ID should be unique there will be only one result and thus no real point in the `.each`.
If you are trying ot iterate over all the children of this element then you can do:

```
 $('#forum').children().each(function (ind){
      ....
 });
```

Another thing, if you want to insert HTML code into a dom element, you should use the `.html()` method rather than the `.text()` method you use:

```
$(this).html(kmsi.replaceURLWithHTMLLinks($(this).text() ) )
```

I didn't go into the regex part.

Comment: thanks. that fixed it. i must have been working too long on it and didn't see the mistakes.